# C#- print the dynamically reducing time

Tags: c#, datetime

I am new to C# and i want to print the time which keeps on changing dynamically.For .e.g. I want to tell the user that he has to type in some command within 10 seconds and then i want that the command prompt starts the time from 10 seconds which keeps on reducing from 10 to 0.
Sorry if i am not clear in explanation.E.g. of such scenario is when windows boot on and does disk check,it asks to hit any key in 10 seconds and the time keeps changing dynamically .i want to try something like that.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 2):

The Timer.Elapsed Event in c# should provide you with the functionality that you need.

[MSDN - Timer.Elapsed Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is a code sample at the bottom of the page.